# chrome: disable internet connection or work offline

Tags: google-chrome, browser, offline

How can I disable internet connection or `work offline` like Firefox in Chrome? I need to check some errors when Internet is not available.

Comment: Great question. I'd like to check if my HTML5 app works with offline-use and I don't want to turn off my entire internet connection, just disable it for the one page I'm viewing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does Chrome have a "Work Offline" option?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16091243/does-chrome-have-a-work-offline-option)

Answer (score 84, accepted):

`offline` mode is added to Chrome v45.

Developer tools -> Network tab -> Choose "offline" from selectbox.

[image]

Comment: Yes but that is not working on websocket or socket connections

Comment: but, only current debugging page offline, other tab(pages) still online.

Comment: great solution! but is there any easy way to access this option or any addon?

Comment: this solution doesn't keep the debugging page from sending network packets.

Comment: **this disables access to `localhost` too**. So technically it's not "no Internet" it's "nothing"

Answer (score 12):

[Offline switcher](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/work-offline/gcjdagaoojgeilcobhibkgbodajcojda/related?hl=en) is a new handy Chrome Extension to do the job quickly.  You can toogle to switch between offline and online mode.

[image: Chrome offline switcher]

The add-on is simple, just to set Chrome proxy to an un-existing point.

Answer (score 4):

Under the network tab, go to the THrottling dropdown where you can select different speeds of web and even set it to be offline. This comes very handy when you are working with service workers and want to test your application in offline mode.

[image]

Refer to the latest answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/32607960/2520254

Comment: Won't work for existing websocket connections: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38729050/chrome-disabling-web-sockets-or-closing-a-web-socket-connection

Answer (score 2):

Until Chrome has a feature to disable internet but retains localhost (or local network) connections. The only way I could suggest is to just disconnect the network from the internet manually for your testing.