# Chrome - Disabling Web Sockets or Closing a Web Socket Connection?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Is there any way to disable web socket connections or end a web socket connection through Chrome's developer tools network tab?

I've noticed that turning throttling under the network tab to *Offline* doesn't affect web socket connections that have already been established.  It only prevents traditional HTTP requests from going out.

There's a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5612158/how-can-i-temporarily-disable-websocket-in-google-chrome) related to this, but it's woefully outdated.

Comment: Doesn't seem possible. [Bitcoinchain](https://bitcoinchain.com/) is an easy site to test on.

Answer (score 34):

### February 2022 update

As of Chrome 99 this is supported: https://developer.chrome.com/blog/new-in-devtools-99/#websocket

### Original answer

No, there is no way to disable or close a connection from the Network panel. Source: DevTools Engineer.

If you have a reference to the WS connection, though, you can close it via the Console using its JS API.

Comment: whats the technical limitation here? without any further knowledge, I'd imagine it would be easy to just have the offline button disable any network communication at all

Comment: It's a matter of prioritization. A DevTools engineer said in this [comment](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=746576#c16) that the existing offline implementation does not affect web socket connections and that it is not an easy fix. If a lot of DevTools users request the feature, the team would reconsider dedicating resources to fixing it.

Comment: This answer can be improved by providing an example of how to find the WebSocket reference and close a WebSocket connection via its JavaScript API.

Comment: [This is now supported](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=423246)

Comment: The newly introduced support is sadly partial: the throttle [does not seem to apply to messages within existing connections](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=423246#c104)

Answer (score 13):

You can close idle and flush your inactive socket pools in the Net Internals page in Chrome. However, this unfortunately only closes your active sockets by the looks of it.

```
chrome://net-internals/#sockets
```

[image: Web Sockets]

You would have to use the [WebSockets API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API) and call [`close()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket#close()) on a reference to an existing socket to close it explicitly. Otherwise, killing the process with the active socket is all I can think of.

Answer (score 7):

Try this, produced by hours of digging for a similar issue I had. Seems to work for me for closing an "existing" connection on demand.

1. Chrome Dev Tools -> Memory tab -> Take Snapshot
2. Once completed, search snapshot on summary tab for "websocket"
3. Expand the results, there might be a few. Usually the one you want is the one that has the correct websocket url field in preview (when you hover over the entry)
4. Select it, right click and "store as global variable"
5. In the console that opens up at the bottom, execute a .close() on the temp variable that the connection was stored on. Probably will be a "temp1.close()".

This approach is similar to another post that recommends pulling a reference from console.dir() . I'm not sure why - but console.dir() approach didnt work for me. But this heap reference did. Adding as an alternative.

Comment: I like this - it works well for me..  thanks

Comment: Gread ideas with the global variable. Works also from sources tab, when you can break your code execution on the right spot.

Comment: Yeah, anywhere you can get a handle on the `WebSocket` instance. Combining this with throttling seems to be the right solution for me to test reconnection behavior.

Answer (score 1):

The only way is to cut down the connection for entire tab.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to test unexpected connection failures, it is possible, but not through Network-tab and you need to be able to log from code.

You can close Websocket connections if you are able to use `console.dir(socket)` even when you could not store the connection reference, e.g. due sandboxing. Via `console.dir()` you are able to gain a reference to the socket by right clicking the `console.dir()` output of the websocket and choosing "Store object as global variable". Then call `close()` on the temporary reference and the connection you want to terminate closes.

[image: Dev tools close connection]