# How to manually disconnect webpack dev server from chrome

Tags: google-chrome, webpack, websocket, google-chrome-devtools, webpack-dev-server

Can I manually disconnect a chrome window from refreshing automatically when I change my code.
Basically I want to disconnect the `websocket` connection using devtool or some other way. I tried offline checkbox, but its not helping.

This will come handy for a HTML developer for him to compare the HTML changes done from a `developer tool` and to the original one.

Answer (score 1):

Right-click the WS connection in the Network panel then select [Block Request URL](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/devtools-release-notes#block-requests). Based on the [websocket.org echo demo](http://www.websocket.org/echo.html), it seems to provide the effect you're looking for.

Comment: tried this now, but this will work only once you refresh the page after blocking the url. May its not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the hot module reload to false? There is mention of it in the [docs](https://webpack.js.org/guides/hot-module-replacement/#enabling-hmr).

Comment: But that will block for all browser windows..right ? I just need to block it for just one window...something to do in browser

Comment: How about this option of closing it in the console using the web sockets JS? https://stackoverflow.com/a/38730831/5086349