# How to simulate tcp connection loss on localhost

Tags: asp.net, websocket, localhost, network-interface

I have a `ASP NET Core` web api that uses websockets. I am trying to find out if the server handles internet connection loss (client side) correctly.

However since I have only one machine on which both the server and the client run, i know that `localhost` does not use the Network Interface, and the desired handler is not triggered when I cut off the internet.

How can I thus have a server that runs a localhost, and a client that also runs on localhost but uses the network interface, so that I can cut the internet off and see how the server behaves for the given client?

Comment: In Google Chrome, have you tried opening up the dev tools to the Network tab, and changing the throttling setting from Online to Offline?

Comment: That is not the case i am looking for. In that case the client closes connection gracefully , sending a `socket - close` message to the server . When internet connection is lost there is no such message sent to the server , and this is the case i am trying to simulate.

Answer (score 1):

I use [TCPView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/tcpview) to do this sort of testing. You can find the connection in the list, then right-click/close it:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Since 2022 this is now supported, setting Chrome dev tools to "Offline" will drop WS connections and you can test your reconnection/error handling logic: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38730831/56621