# why simulating offline in Chrome devtool results in no access to localhost?

Tags: angular, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

[simulating offline state](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32607960/10577976) in chrome dev-tools using 'throttling: offline' result in 'No internet connection' error when trying to access web app(Angular) running on localhost:4200.

[image]

when manually turning off wifi and internet connection the I have access to localhost:4200  with no problem(my app does not require an internet connection to run).

It seems that 'offline' mode does not allow even access to the localhost. why is that the behavior and how can I simulate offline mode in the browser without having to manually turning on and off the internet connection on the system level?

Comment: localhost in your case is nothing else as a simulated server serving your application. This would not work if published. What is your attempt to do? When you applications needs no internet why you try to simulate offline state?

Comment: i just want to test my app in offline mod and online mod efficiently

Comment: Either use PWA features or if it is only about to test how the application behaves when the api cannot be reached, block the api instead. You can block urls und domains in the network tab. maybe you can give this approach a try

Comment: but I  want to block any domain, i want to make sure my app will work offline. there is no way to easily simulate offline mode In devtools?