# How do I deactivate the internet entirely with Firefox's developer tools?

Tags: firefox, web-applications, firefox-developer-tools, offline-browsing

I'm developing in Firefox and was asked today to test connectivity drops. How do I simulate this from the developer tools? All I can see in the network tab is speed throttling, ranging from GPRS to WiFi. How do I disable the internet entirely?

(I can't just turn the laptop's Wi-Fi off, I want the DB GUI up in a separate window.)

I noticed that accoring to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16806343/chrome-disable-internet-connection-or-work-offline), Chrome has this feature, but I don't use Chrome.

Comment: Can't help myself, but "deactivate the internet" reminds me of [this](https://youtu.be/iDbyYGrswtg).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not available in Firefox devtools. You can follow this bug: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1029203

In the meantime, you can use "Work Offline" in the File menu. On Windows, press Alt to show the menu bar: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/restore-menu-bar-firefox#firefox:win11:fx108

Comment: Thanks for the response! Marked as accepted. First created 9 years ago... So you're saying I shouldn't hold my breath? :D